# Express res.render shows 403 forbidden

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am running my website on a Cloud hosting with Centos6. I've installed and ran nodejs and mongodb successfully.

I'm using Express and routing my main directory to an index.hbs file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I load this on my local machine, it works. However, on the hosting it shows a 403 Forbidden page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with file permissions. The user that that you application is running as needs to have read access to the template files.

Another hint is that some place you may be accessing files relative to the current working directory which may not be the same as your application directory when it is run in production.

For example when you start in the root directory and run:

```
cd /your/app; node app.js
```

then both the current working directory and __dirname is the same in app.js, but when you run:

```
node /your/app/app.js
```

then the cwd and __dirname is different.

Those are just some hints because with no log and error messages and no details on how and where your app is running it's impossible to answer in any more detail.